scores = model.evaluate(test_ds) this always gives different results when running it multiple times
when i run this cell its giving me different accuracy.
Why?
How I will fix it?
I have set the seed value.
Fixed the test, train and validation data
I have built a CNN model. and I want a stable answer so that I can fix it. But Its not giving a consistent answer. how to change the code? what are the things that i have to do? Setting up the seed value is not helping.

Please do not post code as images, see here for the reason. Please add the code as text to your question.

Also, please show your model and data creation code (in the question, as text!). Otherwise it's just guessing. Normally, model.evaluate() should give deterministic results.

If your model is stochastic, it will give random outputs at the beginning of training because it starts with randomly initialized parameters (e.g. weights and bias). You can adjust the initialization of these parameters. As the model learns, its output becomes less random.
To solve this, you can make your model deterministic by taking mean $\mu$ as an output and initialize the weights and bias as follows for pytorch:
self.fc = nn.Linear(n, m)
model.fc.weight.fill_(0.3)
model.fc.bias.fill_(0.2)

And for Tensorflow, I found this Kaggele webpage here which explains in detail
However, I need to tell you that sometimes making the model deterministic has some disadvantages.

From the question ("if I run this cell") it seems that the trained model is fixed and only model.evaluate() is re-run. Weight initialization should not be a problem here.
